# Передача всех данных в автопоиск во View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Делаю автопоиск на сайте мой контроллер выглядит следующим образом.

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteSearch(string term)
    {
        var a_suppliers = db.Ue_suppliers.Where(
            a => a.ShortName.Contains(term) ||  a.Manager.Contains(term)
            || a.Name.Contains(term) || a.PhoneManager.Contains(term)
            || a.Phone.Contains(term)
            ).ToList().Select(
            a => new { value = a.Manager }
            ).Distinct();

        return Json(a_suppliers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

То есть менеджера я передаю без проблем, но как мне передать остольные данные? 
Побывал это `a => new { value = a.Manager }` писать чере запятую, ноль реакции

Сделал все по предложеному внизу варианту , все хорошо, но он привязан к параметру value. Вот так выглядит мой View

```
 <input type="text" name="name" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("AutocompleteSearch", "Uchet")"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="Поиск по " />
```

А вот скрипт снизу

```
@section scripts{


    <script>
        $(function () {
         $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
             var target = $(this);
             target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
         });
        });
        </script>
    }
```

Все прекрасно работает, когда делаешь так `a => new { value = a.Manager }`, но стоит мне поменять контроллер, чтобы автопоиск работал о всем полям

```
 public ActionResult AutocompleteSearch(string term)
        {
            var a_suppliers = db.Ue_suppliers.Where(
                a => a.ShortName.Contains(term) ||  a.Manager.Contains(term)
                || a.Name.Contains(term) || a.PhoneManager.Contains(term)
                || a.Phone.Contains(term)
                ).ToList().Select(
                a => new { value = a.Manager, a.Name, a.ShortName, a.PhoneManager, a.Phone
                }
                ).Distinct();

            return Json(a_suppliers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

То он продолжает искать только по Менеджерам, но уже по содержимому объекта.

Как мне сделать,чтобы автопоиск работал по всем записям?

Comment: `new { value = a.Manager, value2 = a.PhoneManager }` так пробовали через запятую?

Comment: убери селект вообще - вернутся все столбцы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто:

```
a => new { manager = a.Manager, name = a.Name, phone = a.Phone, ... }
```

Но в целом лучше объявить отдаваемый класс и создавать его экземпляры, а не анонимные объекты.

```
public class SearchDTO
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    public Manager Manager {get;set;}
    ...
}

a => new SearchDTO{ Manager= a.Manager, Name = a.Name, Phone = a.Phone, ... }
```

Comment: чем лучше например?

Comment: @Grundy 
а) Возможность переиспользования. 
б) Возможность дополнительных проверок в экземпляре, например, ограничить конструкторы. 
в) Возможность автоматической генерации интерфейса, скажем, для TypeScript (чтобы принимающий сервис мог работать с типизированным объектом, а не "угадывать" поля) 
г) Автоматическая генерация документации, скажем, для swagger и т.п.

Comment: какое может быть переиспользование если полученный объект сразу выплевывается в JSON? и в принципе про него на сервере никто не знает. А уж на клиенте что угодно может быть и даже вообще никак не связанное

Comment: @Grundy Он может выплевываться не только отсюда. Например, может быть быстрый поиск для подсказки, может расширенный поиск по параметрам, может быть выдача еще где-то... И во всех этих местах желательно возвращать один объект, а не миллион разных - чтобы не писать на клиенте миллион разных приемников/вью, а написать один, который работает со списком стандартизированных объектов.

Comment: если на клиенте нужно всего одно/два поля из всех, нет смысла слать все 20

Comment: Здесь уже не одно/два. Но для этого можно использовать наследование, SearchShortDTO/SearchFullDTO. Опять же, мы получаем два объекта, а не десяток на каждый метод своих. Кроме того, в случае расширения/изменения отдачи под новые функциональные требования - мы меняем один конструктор/объект - и все остальные места рефакторятся автоматом - вместо того чтобы вспоминать и искать где же у нас возвращались "похожие" объекты.

Comment: То есть вместо того чтобы просто использовать анонимный объект, создавать кучу классов которые будут использоваться в одном месте?

Comment: Зачем кучу? На данный момент я предложил один. Любая отдача веб-метода - это часть контракта веб-сервиса и должна быть формализована. Чтобы любой клиент мог работать с веб-сервисом по единым правилам и знать что именно ему придёт.

Comment: _На данный момент я предложил один._ так в чем тогда его преимущество? если он один - то же самое что и анонимный объект

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44147/discussion-between-grundy-and-lbiss).

Comment: Посмотрите, я использовал Ваш вариант, код не выдал ошибку , но поиск работает не правильно